# dnsjava - Create new Record

Tags: dnsjava

I am assigned a task to update the zone files. And I found [dnsjava](http://www.dnsjava.org/).
However, when using it to add a new Record, I am successfully creating new records using the classes NSRecord, ARecord. But since there are many such classes, can I use Record class to create new record and add it to the zone file.

Using NSRecord, i am able to create a new record using

```
nsRecord = new NSRecord(domainName, dClass, ttl, target);
```

where target is the Name type nameserver.

Record class has the newRecord method to create a new Record, [here](http://www.dnsjava.org/doc/org/xbill/DNS/Record.html#newRecord%28org.xbill.DNS.Name,%20int,%20int,%20long,%20byte[]%29).
But I don't know what the last parameter "data" or type byte[] is and what it does. Also how do I add nameserver values to the record to save to the file.